# Sorting values in a row in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a sample dataset looking like;

```
ID | feature_1_name | feature_1_value | feature_1_score  | feature_2_name | feature_2_value | feature_2_score 
1234|  final_new    | contact        |  2.34            |  subtype       | proprietor       |  -0.78
5678 | iso_code     |  US            | 0.09             |  subtype        | sole             |   1.23
```

The goal is to define anew concatenated column, say `combined_col`, which should look like;

```
combined_col
final_new(2.34, contact); subtype(-0.78, proprietor)
subtype(1.23, sole);  iso_code(0.09,US)
```

So the requirement is to perform the concatenation, but to be made sure that it should be in decreasing order of scores, as shown above. The only idea I can think of is using `CASE` statement but am not sure how to implement it here. Advice/help is appreciated.

**Edit**
Taking into consideration sign of the numbers in `feature_score` column. We need to define two separate columns one with positive `feature_scores` and other with negative `feature_scores`.
Example output:

```
positive_scores          | negative_Scores
final_new(2.34, contact)  | subtype(-0.78, proprietor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll want to get this data into a properly normalized form. Right now you have two sets of columns for each `feature`. Instead you should have a row for each feature:

```
+------+----------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|  ID  | feature_number | feature_name | feature_value | feature_score |
+------+----------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1234 |              1 | final_new    | contact       |          2.34 |
| 5678 |              1 | iso_code     | US            |          0.09 |
| 1234 |              2 | subtype      | proprietor    |         -0.78 |
| 5678 |              2 | subtype      | sole          |          1.23 |
+------+----------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

You can get to this with a UNION:

```
SELECT ID, 1 as feature_number, feature_1_name as feature_name, feature_1_value as feature_value, feature_1_score as feature_score
FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 2 as feature_number, feature_2_name as feature_name, feature_2_value as feature_value, feature_2_score as feature_score
FROM yourtable
```

This serves two purposes:

1. We can easily order by and concatenate using the built in [listagg()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html) function.
2. If you add a feature in the future to each `id` you only need to add new rows, not edit your whole table structure. Although, that's unrelated to the question you are asking.

---

Now that the data is in a more workable format, we can concatenate the data together to get it into your desired `<feature_name>(<feature_value>, <feature_score>)` format and then we use `LISTAGG()` to collapse multiple rows into a single row where we order within the `LISTAGG()` function using the `WITHIN GROUP` keyword.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    LISTAGG(feature_name || '(' || trim(feature_score) || ',' || feature_value || ')', '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY feature_score) as combined_Col
FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, 1 as feature_number, feature_1_name as feature_name, feature_1_value as feature_value, feature_1_score as feature_score
        FROM yourtable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, 2 as feature_number, feature_2_name as feature_name, feature_2_value as feature_value, feature_2_score as feature_score
        FROM yourtable
    ) dt
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Output:

```
+------+---------------------------------------------------+
|  ID  |                   COMBINED_COL                    |
+------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1234 | final_new(2.34,contact); subtype(-0.78,proprietor) |
| 5678 | subtype(1.23,sole); iso_code(0.09,US)              |
+------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: appreciate your reply and willingness to help. My table has millions of rows. so will I need to do UNION ALL of all of them. I am wondering is it going to scale to that magnitude of data complexity. Kindly advise.

Comment: You will still only need a single UNION ALL. Essentially we are just stacking your table on top of itself. In the first half we choose feature_1* columns and in the second half we choose feature_2* columns. The SQL should work as-is without modification. The only reason you would have to add more UNIONs is if you have a set of `feature_3*` columns or `feature_4*` columns.

Comment: thanks for your explanations. appreciate it. As an addition, is it possible to use the same idea to extend and make two different sorted columns, one column for positive feature scores and other for negative scores. plz see edits above in original post.